# Access the kubernetes dashboard via https

Tags: kubernetes

I've started `kube-apiserver` with the CA authentication with `--secure-port=8181`, and the insecure address and port is the default one(`localhost:8080`):

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at localhost:8080
kubernetes-dashboard is running at localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
```

The page of `kubernetes-dashboard` in browser returns me the following error:

```
Get http://localhost:8080/api/v1/replicationcontrollers: dial tcp [::1]:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
```

But the url "http**S**://domain:**8181**/api/v1/replicationcontrollers" will return the RCs as well.

So is there a way to use the secure port only? I mean that getting the access of kubernetes dashboard via https.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose any Kubernetes Service via https by deploying an Ingress controller in front of it, like nginx: https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx. This nginx controller will terminate tls, so even if your backend doesn't support https it should work. There are several ways to *enforce* https through it: https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx#server-side-https-enforcement

Comment: do you mean  I can manage the `apiserver` behind the ingress controller? how to specify the backend `serviceName` of apiserver in the ingress rc file?